# Avoid boilerplate in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

My APIs respect the conventional status codes and I have found myself repeating the same text in the responses part of my api definition

```
404:
          description: The resource doesn't exist
          schema:
            $ref:   '#/definitions/Error'
default:
          description: An unexpected error has occurred
          schema:
            $ref:   '#/definitions/Error'
```

A similar problem I also encounter is that I can't factor out enum properties and parameters. Can my Swagger code become more dry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your code can become far more dry: the OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) specification offers many ways of factoring things, including responses, parameters and enums.

**Reusable responses**

You can define reusable response almost the same way you defined `Error`in your example.

First add response, for example `Standard404`, definition in `responses` on root level

```
responses:
  Standard404:
    description: The resource doesn't exist
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

Then, use it with a `$ref : '#/responses/Standard404'` for 404 status code in `responses` on any operation

```
responses:
  404:
    $ref: '#/responses/Standard404'
```

**Reusable parameters**

For reusable parameters, it's the same thing.

First add a parameter, for example `ID`, definition in `parameters` on root level:

```
parameters:
  ID:
    name: id
    in: path
    required: true
    type: string
```

Then use it in any list of parameters with a `$ref: '#/parameters/ID'`.
*Pro tip*: parameters can be defined on operation level but also on path level:

```
  /other-resources/{id}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/ID'

 /resources/{id}:
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/parameters/ID'
```

**Reusable enums**

All you need to do is to define a definition of type string (or integer or number) with the enum:

```
SomeValueWithEnum:
    type: string
    enum:
      - a value
      - another value
```

And then use it as many times as you wish like this:

```
 Resource:
    properties:
      dummyProperty:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SomeValueWithEnum'
```

**Full example**

Here's a full example for these 3 use cases:

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: API
  description: Reusable things example

paths:

  /resources:
    post:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
        default:
          $ref: '#/responses/Default'

  /resources/{id}:
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/parameters/ID'
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
        404:
          $ref: '#/responses/Standard404'
        default:
          $ref: '#/responses/Default'
    delete:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
        404:
          $ref: '#/responses/Standard404'
        default:
          $ref: '#/responses/Default'

  /other-resources/{id}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/ID'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
        404:
          $ref: '#/responses/Standard404'
        default:
          $ref: '#/responses/Default'

definitions:
  Error:
    properties:
      message:
        type: string

  SomeValueWithEnum:
    type: string
    enum:
      - a value
      - another value

  Resource:
    properties:
      dummyProperty:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SomeValueWithEnum'

  AnotherResource:
    properties:
      anotherDummyProperty:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SomeValueWithEnum'

parameters:
  ID:
    name: id
    in: path
    required: true
    type: string

responses:
  Standard404:
    description: The resource doesn't exist
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
  Default:
    description: An unexpected error has occurred
    schema:
      $ref:   '#/definitions/Error'
```

**More about this**
You should read this [tutorial](http://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-1-introduction/) (disclosure: I wrote it) and the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md).

Comment: Is it also possible to factor out enums?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 If "factor out enums" means "can I define a reusable enum", the answer is no. All you can do is define a reusable property with an enum (as shown in my answer). Maybe I should add this precision to my answer. Does my understanding of your comment is correct?

Comment: @ArnaudLauret - I have an openAPI spec where many endpoints have identical 401, 404, and 5XX responses, in addition to the 200 response which is different for each endpoint. I've tried mixing a specific 200 response with ` $ref: '#/components/responses/common_errors'`, but I get a warning `sibling values alongside $refs are ignored` and the error `... should only have three-digit status codes`. Is there a way to dry up several response codes duplicated across different endpoints?